# Azure - This Service is unhealthy .NET Backend

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, asp.net-web-api2

I have constructed an API using webapi2.2.

When I deploy the API to Azure I get the Service Unhealthy Message...when I check the logs of my API the log gives the error message

> "Boot strapping failed: executing 'WebApiConfig.Register' caused an
>   exception: 'Parameter count mismatch.'.

The Application Start function is below

```
protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
```

And my WebApiConfig.cs has the following:

```
  public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.EnableCors();

        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.
                    SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));.......
```

Another question here: The api implements its own Security mechanism (I used the following as a reference http://bitoftech.net/2014/12/15/secure-asp-net-web-api-using-api-key-authentication-hmac-authentication/). Would this implementation work in Azure or would you have to make use of the x-zumo header authorisation mechanism?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the resolution to this - I believe that the problem is caused by the fact that I have another mobile services app running in my Azure account. That app was built awhile ago - early 2015 and used the register procedure with no parameters

```
 public static void Register(){.....}
```

I think that this may have confused the service operation (the fact that one app has a register without parameters and the other has a register with one parameter). To resolve the issue with my new app I removed the config parameter, and build the config settings in the register function see below

```
  public static void Register()
    {

        ConfigOptions options = new ConfigOptions();

        HttpConfiguration config = ServiceConfig.Initialize(new ConfigBuilder(options));
        config.EnableCors();.....
```

Remember though you will need access to the using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.Service namespace...this can be obtained by installing the nuget package WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Backend

Hope this helps someone who has similar problems